# Webworker load fonts

Tags: javascript, canvas, fonts, web-worker

Webworkers can writre text to offscreen canvas, but can they stylize that text with custom fonts?

Lets have in mind a worker can call xhttp to get the fonts raw data. What must be done after that?

I only know workers do not have access to fonts loaded from the webpage.

eg in worker

```
ctx.font = '... [custom font]';
ctx.fillText('FOONT', 20, 20);
```

gets me all the time simple serif font.

Thanks

Comment: Text is styled by CSS. It has nothing to do with webworkers.

Comment: No css available in workers . . .

Comment: Do you actually need a worker, or do you just need an [offscreen canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas)?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans why would anyone need an OffscreenCanvas if not to use it on a Worker?

Comment: double buffering comes to mind

Comment: Oh sorry for the duplicate. I wrote that on mobile version and so i got no similar question suggestions.

Comment: @ituy no worries, it's all fine to have duplicates, we actually like them, when they are well written and will help in the future to find the answers thanks to different wordings.